# How can i secure a dockerized vue app with nginx?

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx

I have created a Vue app and following the cookbook I have made the docker image and it runs just fine, the problem is that I use [Vue Qrcode Reader](https://gruhn.github.io/vue-qrcode-reader/api/QrcodeStream.html#browser-support) and in the TroubleShooting, it says that for me to use the app from my cellphone it has to be secured through HTTPS i have little to no knowledge on what to do.

This is my docker File:

```
# etapa de compilación
FROM node:current-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# etapa de producción
FROM nginx:1.19.2-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I use Nginx to serve my application so the approach i that i consider is to configure the nginx server to make the connection secure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Vue, but in theory you should be able to get a HTTPS connection by installing a TLS certificate on your nginx server.

I would recommend checking out Let's Encrypt for getting a TLS certificate for your nginx server. Nginx has a document for setting up Let's Encrypt with nginx available here:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/

It's not really worth copying the details here, since it does change dramatically from time to time.

Comment: so i should create the configuration file and copy it to the docker image when the build process is made? and should i install the certbot directly inside the image